# Consolidate nested arrays and erase the subarrays that have been consolidated?

Tags: ruby, arrays, t9

I'm trying to take a bunch of number-word pairs and group the words according to common numbers. I can match the numbers, merge the subarrays that share the number, and erase the first of those subarrays. But when I try to delete the second, I get this error:

"in `block in <main>': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

The guilty line -- ary.delete_at(i+1) -- has been commented out. Secondary problem: MRBTree is not taking the nested arrays as input...

```
ary = [[2.28, "cat"], [2.28, "bat"], [2.327, "bear"], [2.68, "ant"], [2.68, "anu"]]
i = 0

for i in 0 ... ary.size - 1
    if ary[i][0] == ary[i+1][0]
        b = (ary[i]+ary[i+1]).uniq
        ary.delete_at(i)
                # ary.delete_at(i+1)
        c = [b.first], b.pop(b.length - 1)
        h = Hash[*c]
        ary.push(*h)
        # mrbtree = MultiRBTree[c]
    end
end

puts ary.inspect
```

output:

```
# => [
# =>   [2.28, "bat"], 
# =>   [2.327, "bear"], 
# =>   [2.68, "anu"], 
# =>   [
# =>     [2.28], ["cat", "bat"]
# =>   ], 
# =>   [
# =>     [2.68], ["ant", "anu"]
# =>   ]
# => ]
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to expose which is the result you're looking for.

Comment: What is the final output you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is failing because you are modifying the array (which has impact on `a.size`) in the loop. The loop end condition is not adjusted automagically. You are accessing things you have deleted before.

If your array is not too big, this will do:

```
p Hash[ary.group_by(&:first).map { | k, v | [k, v.map(&:last)] }]
# => {2.28=>["cat", "bat"], 2.327=>["bear"], 2.68=>["ant", "anu"]}
```

It works this way:

```
ary.group_by(&:first)   # group the 2-elem arrays by the number, creating a hash 
                        #     like {2.28=>[[2.28, "cat"], [2.28, "bat"]], ...}
.map  { | k, v | ... }  # change the array of key-value pairs to
[k, v.map(&:last)]      # pairs where the value-array contains just the strings
Hash[ ... ]             # make the whole thing a hash again
```

Creating an intermediate array and transferring it back to a hash is some overhead. If this turns out to be an issue, something like this might be better:

```
h = Hash.new { | a, k | a[k] = [] }   # a hash with [] as default value
p ary.inject(h) { | a, (k, v) | a[k] << v; a }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after

```
ary.delete_at(i)
```

the size of array is decreased by one, hence `i` is better than `i+1`:

```
# ary.delete_at(i+1)
ary.delete_at(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate version for converting to hash:

```
ary = [[2.28, "cat"], [2.28, "bat"], [2.327, "bear"], [2.68, "ant"], [2.68, "anu"]]
hsh = {}

ary.each {|pair| hsh[pair[0]].nil? ? hsh[pair[0]] = [pair[1]] : hsh[pair[0]] << pair[1]}

puts hsh.inspect  # => {2.28 => ["cat", "bat"], 2.327 => ["bear"], 2.68 => ["ant", "anu"]}
```